# Worklight 6.2. Direct Update upload the full web part?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I'm making tests with Direct Update because a requirement of making daily updates to an Android App with look & feel changes.

What I have seen is that all the web files are uploaded and not only the new ones or the updated ones.

Is it possible to make a direct update of specific files?

For example I have an application with images and the size of all those images is 20mg, I make a change to a .css file. The direct update will contain my updated .css but also the 20mg of images that already are in the app and are exactly the same. Is it possible to upload only the .css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in the current releases of Worklight.

However, starting Worklight 6.3, [which will be publically available in December 2014](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=an&subtype=ca&appname=gpateam&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS214-368), the Direct Update feature is extended to support "Differential Direct Update".

With this feature it will no longer be necessary for the client application to download the entire web resources on every update. Instead, only the resources that were changed will be downloaded and updated.

More on that as 6.3 goes public and documentation becomes publicly available.